# WebRtc video chat: not all users see each other

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn, xirsys

I use WebRtс to create a general video chat for 3 users, but the following happens: 1 user sees 2, but these two users see only the first one. This problem is not reproducible if users are on my local network, although I have configured STUN/TURN server (i use https://global.xirsys.net/), also in rare cases (about 10%) all work without error. According to the logs, my code works out correctly, so I see no reason to throw it off. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: It's a pain in the neck to interpret the information in chrome://webrtc-internals/  ... but it may help you understand which ICE candidate pairs get rejected in any given setup. I assume you're using a mesh configuration, in which each endpoint connects to two others. Please consider [edit]ing your question to give more information.

Comment: Yes, i use mesh configuration: each user connect with others.

Comment: Tell me if you need to provide any other additional information.